# How to make containers constant size and scrollable in both directions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, scrollable, singlechildscrollview

I have the following simple code:

```dart
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('D E S K T O P'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                width: constraints.maxWidth * (3 / 4),
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth / 4,
                  color: Colors.red),
            ), //), //Text('hi'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

It creates 2 simple containers. But when I resize the Chrome window, containers also resize and don't have scrollability. What I want to have is containers with constant sizes that are scrollable in both horizontal and vertical directions.

Comment: "What I want to have is containers with constant sizes that are scrollable in both horizontal and vertical directions." - you should use `InteractiveViewer` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide two different controllers on them.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
   controller: ScrollController(),
```

To have horizontal scroll use another `SingleChildScrollView` on body

```dart
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final topController = ScrollController();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('D E S K T O P'),
      ),
      body: Scrollbar(
        controller: topController,
        thumbVisibility: true,
        scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: topController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: 1300,
                  width: 200,
                ),
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: ScrollController(),
                child: Container(
                  height: 1300,
                  width: 800,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ), //), //Text('hi'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me `[ERROR:accessibility_bridge.cc(76)] Failed to update ui::AXTree, error: Nodes left pending by the update: 7` error.

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. Also the issue is open[98099](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98099)

Comment: The error disappeared by stopping/running the application, but the problem is that the page is not still scrollable horizontally.

Comment: Ok let me add a scrollbar to make it easier

Comment: Also the containers resize by resizing the window, I want to keep them fixed sized.

Comment: if you dont like to resize, you dont need to use LayoutBuilder constraints, check update snippet

Comment: That's right, I got it. Just one other question, How to make the entire page scrollable in both directions, not the widget separately?

Comment: You might be looking for [InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html)

Comment: Can't I use two nested `SingleChildScrollView` or there is no property to add both directions?

Comment: Is it OK to put the whole page with a tons of widgets inside a `InteractiveViewer` widget?

Comment: I dont about others unless you wrap widget with both direction as I did, better option is using `InteractiveViewer`